# c2dm receives NotRegistered after gcm registration

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I've run into a pretty bizarre problem with c2dm.  Seeing as it's deprecated, I've begun the process of migrating to gcm.  Due to the design of this product, I can't simply register for gcm and send the new registration id to my backend and forget about c2dm.  I need to have both c2dm and gcm registered on the phone for my app at the same time.  I'm two separate sender accounts, one for c2dm and one for gcm.

The problem is that, if there's an existing c2dm registration and i then register for gcm, further push notifications to the c2dm registration id will receive NotRegistered from google.  If I register for c2dm and gcm at the same time, both work fine for about an hour, at which point I suddenly start getting NotRegistered from google on the c2dm account.  gcm pushes continue to work fine.

Anyone run into something like this?

Comment: I seem to be encountering this...although in my case, it is GCM that stops working after an hour. Perhaps this is because I register for GCM first and C2DM second.

Comment: btw...because your question is "Anyone run into something like this?", I was tempted to post an answer that just says: "Yes."
xD

Comment: Good point ;-D  Yeah I eventually ran into the problem going both directions also.  Never have found any workaround.

Comment: Maybe this would be overkill, I don't know...but perhaps you could have a "puppet app" which registers for C2DM using a different application id? Then as far as google is concerned, there's your main app registering for GCM and an entirely separate app registering for C2DM, and it should maintain both registrations. The challenge would be how to conveniently bundle the puppet app with the main one. Just a thought...